# Returning a column value only if it has one record in another table

Tags: sql

I am using this SQL statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.*, b.WorkOrderNumber
FROM
    Database.dbo.FirstTable a
LEFT JOIN
    Database.dbo.SecondTable b ON a.Plant = b.Plant 
                               AND a.JCNumber = b.JCNumber
WHERE 
    1 = 1 
    AND a.ApprovalStatus = 'A'  
    AND a.Plant = 610
ORDER BY 
    a.JCDate, a.EmployeeNumber ASC
```

In the first table there are unique rows that can have multiple records tied by a foreign key in second table. For instance there is a record in FirstTable that has a primary key of 2 and in the second table there are 1 or more child records with that foreign key of 2.

One of the columns in the second table is 'WorkOrderNumber'. From my SQL statement, I only want to populate the column 'WorkOrderNumber' that I added before the 'FROM' if there is 1 record in that SecondTable. If there are multiple records in the second table just leave the column blank.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Can you maybe add some sort of mini dataset to make it easily reproducible?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_ and _rows_, not fields or records.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: @jarlh terminology referencing the same thing.

Comment: @jarlh that link you posted, said add code as text to my question which i did. how do i add a mini dataset to it so it can be reproducible?

Comment: column <> field example: `select (a, b) as c from t` returns one (row-type) column `c` - which consists of the two fields `a` and `b`.

Comment: You have to figure out the sample data. Some rows that cover the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `Database.dbo.SecondTable` with a simple subselect that retains the plants with exactly one record:

```
(Select Plant, max(WorkOrderNumber) as WorkOrderNumber
 From Database.dbo.SecondTable
 Group By Plant Having count(*)=1)
```

That should be all you need - the Left Join will only give workorders for plants with one record

Comment: this worked for me, i modified it slightly. thank you and i appreciate the simple and quick answer

Comment: SELECT distinct a.*, b.WorkOrderNumber FROM Database.dbo.FirstTable a left join (Select JCNumber, Plant, max(WorkOrderNumber) as WorkOrderNumber
 From Database.dbo.SecondTable  Group By JCNumber, Plant Having count(*)=1) as b on a.JCNumber = b.JCNumber